# Search by first item of nest field List<object> in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How can i search by first item of nest field type List in elasticsearch?

```
 public class Data
 {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<History> Logs{get;set;}
 }
 public class History
 {
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
 }
```

Example, i have 3 records like as:

```
PUT /my_index/Data/1
{
  "name": "name 1",
  "logs": [ 
    {
      "status":    "2",
      "note": "processed",
      "dateProcessed":    "2016-04-11"
    },
    {
      "status":    "1",
      "note": "new",
      "dateProcessed":    "2016-04-10"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /my_index/Data/2
{
  "name": "name 2",
  "logs": [ 
    {
      "status":    "1",
      "note": "new",
      "dateProcessed":    "2016-04-11"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /my_index/Data/3
{
  "name": "name 2",
  "logs": [ 
    {
      "status":    "3",
      "note": "error",
      "dateProcessed":    "2016-04-11"
    },
    {
      "status":    "1",
      "note": "new",
      "dateProcessed":    "2016-04-10"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, i want to get records which have first item of list (field logs) with status equal 1.
In above example, result is second record.
Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-script-query.html), but that would be very slow.

```
 {
"filter": {
    "script": {
       "script": "_source.logs?.first()?.status.equals('1')"
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure to [enable scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Answer (score 0):

The way you should go seems like [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

You should define your list as Nested during mapping. Then you can write Nested Queries on them and filter your "Data" depending on inner hits of "History".